# saltstack best practices on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, salt-stack, infrastructure, orchestration

I have been using saltstack for a few years with bare metal server. Now we need to setup a whole new environment on AWS. I'd prefer to use saltstack set everything up because I like the orchestration of salt and the event based stuff, like beacons & reactors. Plus it's easy to write your own customised python module. We will also be running kubernetes clusters on EC2 instances. Can someone provide some best practices for using salt with AWS and k8s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s a few reusable setups floating around, last I remember https://github.com/valentin2105/Kubernetes-Saltstack was the most complete of them. But all of them are less solid than tools closer to the community mainstream (kops, kubespray) so beware of weird problems. I would recommend going through Kubernetes The Hard Way just so you have some familiarity with the underlying components that make up Kubernetes so you’ll have a better chance of debugging them :)